# How to show points on LineString in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, line, linestring, visualisation

I created a shape file with the following schema in python:

```
    schema = {
        "geometry": "LineString",
        "properties": {"id": "int"},
    }
```

When I import this shape file to QGIS I don't see where the vertices/points of this polyline are, is there a way to show them?

[image]

Comment: you want to show the vertices of the linestring?

Comment: yep exactly, want to show that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new symbol layer ([image: 4]) of type [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) and select the geometry type to **Point / Multi Point** use this expression: `nodes_to_points($geometry)`.
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 5):

Add a new symbol layer of type `marker line` and opt to show a marker `on every vertex`. Eventually click on the said marker to customize it.

[image]